# pandas datetime column, comparing to datetime variables: TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to see if the 'DateTime_Added' rows in the df are within the last 2 days of the execution date.

```
execution_date = context.get("execution_date")

printed execution_date: `2022-02-14T01:00:00+00:00`

printed type execution_date: `<class 'pendulum.datetime.DateTime'>`
```

---

```
last_2_days=execution_date - timedelta(hours=48)
printed last_2_days: 2022-02-12T01:00:00+00:00
printed type last_2_days: <class 'pendulum.datetime.DateTime'>
```

---

I've converted the `DateTime_Added` col to datetime because it was string before:

```
df['DateTime_Added'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime_Added'])
print df.info()

DateTime_Added   2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
comment                 3080 non-null   object
```

then when I try to run this I see `can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`:

```
if row['comment'] is not None and row['comment'] != '' and 
  row['DateTime_Added'] is not None and row['DateTime_Added'] != ''
  and (last_2_days <= row['DateTime Comment Added'] <= execution_date):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pendulum datetime enforces timezone by default (which is the 00:00 offset here), and the `df['DateTime_Added']` series does not have a timezone. This means the two can't be compared, which is what the error is indicating.
Pendulum has the `naive()` helper method to remove offset from the datetime object.
Running `last_2_days = pendulum.naive(last_2_days)` before doing the comparison should resolve the error.